# My boss is leaving and his boss is ignoring me

Tags: management

My boss's boss only visits our office for a couple of days a month. A day or so after my boss handed in his resignation boss's boss came for her regular monthly visit. I've never actually had a 1 to 1 with her before as I didn't want to go above my boss (who has only been my boss for about a year)'s head, but under the circumstances I felt it was appropriate and my boss agreed. So did boss's boss, she said I am perfectly entitled to go above boss's head and talk to her about anything whenever I need to, She doesn't know me very well, but I explained my case, felt like I was trying to sell myself at a job interview.

There is always the worry and very real risk that senior management will get rid of all of us in our office and take our work to the main office they work from. I asked to be involved in the future plans. She was very positive, it was too early days at the time for any decisions on how the future is going to pan out, and no immediate hurry, boss is on a 3 month notice period.

1 month on and she comes for her next visit. Not a word is mentioned about 'the plan' - she goes off back to her main office. A couple of days later I send her an email asking for a phone chat. No-one's heard anything but there have been murmurings.

This task that boss does is being taken over by so-and-so in main office and this other task that boss does is being taken over by another so-and-so in main office. Looks like plans are being made without my knowledge or involvement, exactly what I didn't want.

I'm entitled to talk to her, she said that, but my email has gone unanswered. So what next? I don't want to sit back and just let whatever is going to happen happen without being involved but I also don't want to be a nuisance and get on her nerves. There's not just me to consider, I have 7 direct reports who are also worried, I have a duty to look after them. Maybe I give it a week and try phoning her?

Comment: Is there only 1 email that has been ignored? Could have just been lost in the mix or forgotten about. It doesn't sound like you've taken nearly enough action on this to be considered a nuisance.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend **waiting at least a week to get the reply** before considering sending another one. However, I also strongly believe that **reaching to her via phone call would be more effective and efficient**, given that she doesn't mind or gave you permission to reach out this way.

Seems to me that your main worry is the chance that your boss leaving means that you will also follow him shortly; it is understandable you want to seek answers, specially if you have people under your direction.

Given all this, I suggest you reach out to her and express your (and your reports') concern in a more direct manner. Probably now she has a better idea of what is coming in the future, and she will give you a clearer answer.

I also suggest mentioning in some way that this is also a worry present among your reports, as this will give more strength and importance to your inquire and increase the chances of getting a non-dismissive answer.

Now, if you get evasive or not clear answer again, then perhaps a safe move would be to **update your CV and start looking for other job opportunities in case your worries become true**. This you could advise to your reports if you consider necessary (which you seem to believe), but be careful the way you do it to avoid panic or unexpected negative consequences from doing so.

Comment: A lot can happen in a week - I'd only wait a couple of days to try following up.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can escalate issues to a higher boss, but you should go through your immediate boss first unless the problem is specifically about your immediate boss.

If your whole group is getting whacked it is highly unlikely that anyone will tell you this in advance. The company doesn't want everyone leaving before plans are in place to move/handle the work elsewhere. Such plans are also in general never discussed with lower level employees because the lower level employees would immediate start gossiping among themselves and with other employees in other groups that are not getting cut. Employers are also wary of disgruntled employees sabotaging the business in one way or another. So all you can do is plan for the worse and hope for the best.

In this day and age it seems that deep loyalty to employees is gone. You should always be aware of what other jobs are available to you.  Also what additional skills you need to make yourself more marketable.